# simplest python equivalent to R's grepl

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

Is there a simple/one-line python equivalent to R's `grepl` function?

```
strings = c("aString", "yetAnotherString", "evenAnotherOne") 
grepl(pattern = "String", x =  strings) #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
strings = ["aString", "yetAnotherString", "evenAnotherOne"]

["String" in i for i in strings]
#Out[76]: [True, True, False]
```

Or use `re` module:

```
import re

[bool(re.search("String", i)) for i in strings]
#Out[77]: [True, True, False]
```

Or with `Pandas` (R user may be interested in this library, using a dataframe "similar" structure):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(strings).str.contains('String').tolist()
#Out[78]: [True, True, False]
```

Comment: I take it the former solution wouldn't work for `"String$"` right? (i.e. it's just substring match)

Comment: true you will need to use the regex module in that case.

Answer (score 4):

A one-line equivalent is possible, using `re`:

```
import re

strings = ['aString', 'yetAnotherString', 'evenAnotherOne']
[re.search('String', x) for x in strings]
```

This won’t give you boolean values, but truthy results that are just as good.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need a regular expression, but are just testing for the existence of a susbtring in a string:

```py
["String" in x for x in strings]
```