# grepl function in python

Tags: python, r, grepl

I want to recreate a snippet code from R to Python. I have this tibble from R (dataframe in Python)  which is somehow look like this:

```
column1       column2                                 column3
amsterdam     het dag calamiteit bij doen gratis dag  2013
rotterdam     blijdorp groet gratis burp het ik ben   2015
```

with this code below, I tried to extract description as single character string.
This is the code:

```
#R code
for (i in 1:nrow(tibble)) {
    des <- pull(tibble[i,2])
}

#Python code
for i in df:    
    des = df['column2'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
```

and then the series of **des** (we got from df['column']) would look like this in python:

```
het
dag
calamiteit
bij
doen
gratis
dag
blijdorp
groet
burp
het
ik
ben
```

But, then I want to recreate this code from R to Python which I don't know how:

```
if (grepl("^\\s*$", des) == TRUE) { # if description is only whitespace then skip
    trns <- tibble(translatedText = "", detectedSourceLanguage = "", text = "")
```

especially the **grepl** function.

What does it equal to in Python? and what's the best Python code to recreate that? thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simplest python equivalent to R's grepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745710/simplest-python-equivalent-to-rs-grepl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a perfect to recreate the R script from above. This is the Python code:

```
 if [re.match(r'^\s*$', i) for i in des]:
        trns = i
```

so if I have a series of strings like this:

```
root
wit
geel

with
asd

goed
black
red
```

then after I run it with if statement, then I would get result like this:

```
[None,
None,
None,
None,
None,
None,
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=' '>,
None,
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>,
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match=' '>]
```

Answer (score 0):

A nearly exact equivalent of grepl is re.match.
See this small example:

```
import re
data = ["00het", "dags"]

matches = [re.match(r"\d{2}", str_) for str_ in data]
```

While the first string has a match, the other string is None since there aren´t two digits in it. 
I hope this may be a good starting point for you to translate you expression from R to python

Comment: what is **("^\\s*$")** from R is equals in Python then? @Felix

Comment: regex is languag independent. Python specific is, that you have a "r" prefix to mark a regex string.